# Might be early but here we go

Tags: riddle, pattern, lateral-thinking

> Gleefully, we *p*layed together in this winter season
>
> *U*p until now, we have thought this fun will last forever
>
> Ultimately, everything is *n*ot unlimited but has a start and end.
>
> Grinning like a *C*heshire cat is what we want
>
> Look at us struggling, *t*o be happy every day/
>
> Doing our best every day, trying to still smile to remove all
>   *u*nhappiness
>
> So that we're more immune to disease *a*nd make us happier
>
> Nine reasons *t*o [keep
>   smiling](https://www.hercampus.com/school/queens-u/9-reasons-keep-smiling)
>
> *I*t is our pleasure to spread the love
>
> Relief yourself from loneliness because *o*nly few people would be
>   able to appreciate a new beginning
>
> Keep your chin up, *n*o matter the hardship

Can you guess what I would like to convey?

> *First* of all I will give you some hints.
>  The word containing number is literally number, not a combination of *letter*.
>  Uppercase the first and fourth letter after the slash, the rest *of* the letters are lowercase.
>  Combine *each* result you get to obtain a link.
>  Only vocal *sentence* is coded using custom number rot, not the word.
>  **Extra hint:**
>  original -> custom rot
>  a -> a
>  i -> g
>  since it's been revealed that
>  o -> u

**I have something to apologize:**

> - First one was for the incomplete or misguiding instruction such as the initial ***"rot not the word"*** or the  ***vocal*** part which are supposed to be ***vowel***.
>   - Second one is for the custom rot. It was a failure on my part. ***I deeply apologize to everyone who tried to solved the custom rot part.*** I was using a <10 and >10 rule for the rot.
>  Number 10 was taken from line number 10 of the text which is: *"Relief yourself from loneliness because only few people would be able to appreciate a new beginning"*
>
>  <10 rule that I use was:
>  1 (a) = 1x1 + (1-1) x1 = 1 (a)
>  5 (e) = 5x1 + (5-1) x1 = 9 ( i )
>  9 (i) = 9x1 + (9-1) x 3 = 33 ( g )
>
>
>  and the >10 rule was:
>  15 (o) = 5x3 + (5-3) x 3 = 21 ( u )
>  21 (u) = 7x3 + (7-3) x4 = 37 ( k )
>  which aren't supposed to be like that since the rule was broken with the x4.

Comment: What does 'rot not the word' mean? I'm lost here.

Comment: It probably refers to rot algorithms, however i have not found how rot fits here

Comment: it's a custom number rot which means I used special way to rot the letter for sentence. not the word to refute the initial post so as to not misleading :)

Comment: Are you saying we'll get a hyperlink we need to go to? Like a website? Also, the word we find is not rot'ed, but if we say it out loud, that is? I still don't understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: yeah you'll get a gibberish hyperlink. but the hint was there to guide you to get the correct one

Comment: With the given custom rot, do they exchange with each other, or only in one direction?

Comment: custom rot is only 1 direction from original to custom rot. they have a set of operation and rule for it to be like that

Comment: in which case, hasn't it been revealed that u -> o rather than o -> u?

Comment: nope, it was o -> since original was goo.gl not guu.gl

Comment: wouldnt that make it goo.gl -> iuu.il as i -> g?

Comment: my comment on your answer which is take a good care of the hint, one of it refers to "Only vocal sentence is coded using custom number rot, not the word." do note that sentence here was the link. which means only vocal letter on the link was custom rot-ed

Comment: Oh Sorry, I didn't know what was meant by "vocal letters". I now assume it meant vowels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> OK, finally I got to the [Christmas tree](http://goo.gl/Ds9eRu), created in Python for us!
>
>
>  The italic letters in the text read
>  p U n C t u a t I o n

The hint gives us:

> Again combining the italicised text we get the hidden hint "First letter of each sentence". Assuming that the puzzle needs to be read like an acrostic, we get:
>  GUUGLDS9IRK (here I used also the instruction "the word containing number is a number"

Using the punctuation as found by @shinkuro we get:

> Guu.gl/Ds9Irk, which using the updated rules converts to [goo.gl/Ds9eRu](http://goo.gl/Ds9eRu).
>  Please note that without the recommended capitalisation of the 1st and the 4th letters after the slash, the link won't work.

Can you guess what I would like to convey?

> I can't guess anything else apart from that we are all wished a Merry Christmas and a Happy New 2019. Also there is a link in the puzzle to an article called 'Nine reasons to keep smiling'. The Christmas tree is shown with 9 layers but I don't think that's related. In any case:
>  **Keep smiling!**

Comment: close enough.you're still missing something for what you get.

Comment: not quite there @shinkuro answer is right for guu.gl/Ds9iRk (guu.gl->goo.gl) but quite awkward for the "p U n C t u I o n" part. yours is the right one "p U n C t u a t I o n". the goo.gl/ds9grk and goo.gl/23936 was incorrect.

Comment: remember the 4th letter not 4th index after slash number wasn't count as letter

Comment: @Mukyuu Do you mean I've found yet another incorrect address?

Comment: Now you got the link right. But "Can you guess what I would like to convey?"

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping up what we've achieved between us:

> Each italicised letter combined to give us the clue: PUNCTUATION
>  The only punctuation in the passage is a . and a /
>  This punctuation is often used in web links.
>  Reading the hint, the italicised words read out: First Letter Of Each Sentence.
>  From the passage, the first letter of each sentence (aka the acrostic), is GUUGLDSNIRK.
>  However, the hint: *"The word containing number is literally number, not a combination of letter."* means that the letter N which we derived from NINE should become the number 9.
>  Making this change, and adding in the punctuation makes GUU.GL/DS9IRK
>  The next hint: *"Uppercase the first and fourth letter after the slash, the rest of the letters are lowercase."* makes the link become guu.gl/Ds9Irk or guu.gl/Ds9iRk, depending on whether the "fourth letter" includes the number 9 in the counting or not.
>  The extra hints say that the vowels have come out of a custom rot algorithm, with A staying the same and I coming from G. Google has a link shortening system which shortens to goo.gl so this means that U has come from O.
>  This makes the link either goo.gl/Ds9gRk or goo.gl/Ds9Grk.
>  However, these links both lead no where and this is as far as we've gotten.

Comment: I don't mind using what I found and wrote but at least you can quote me.

Comment: @rhsquared I didn't use your answer when I worked out mine though?

Comment: take a good use of the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Partial

> from hint it says that number literally a number
>  so the first letter from each line should be "**G U U G L D S 9 I R K**"
>  then there's italic word from the puzzle which said "**p U n C t u a t I o n**"
>  also notice that he hinted "Combine each result you get to obtain a **link**." so the answer is a link format
>
>
>  now we know that the answer is a link format and on the 3rd and 5th line there're "." and "/"
>  now we end up with something like this **GUU.GL/DS9IRK**
>  and it's stated on the hint "Uppercase the **first and fourth letter** after the slash, the rest of the letters are lowercase."
>  so now we have something like this "**guu.gl/Ds9iRk**"  < notice that 9 is a number and not a letter
>  and since the answer is a link, **guu.gl** should become **goo.gl**
>
>
>  and... here's where i got stuck..
>  the custom rot we all know is a=a, i=g and o=u but idk the formula...
>  i hope someone can solve the problem with this help

Comment: close enough :)